# Alternatives to Dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

At the moment I have data being read into my program being generated by a third party device. I am sending this over a string made up of two separate values joined together and separated by a dash and a full stop. I had initially placed this data in a dictionary using the first value as a key (as its a constant) and the second as its value as it could change at any moment.

With the dictionary I was sorting it so that the values were arranged in descending order so that the lowest value was the first entry in the dictionary, the second lowest was the second and so on. I believed this was also updating so that if the 5 entry was suddenly lower than the first, it would move its position to be the first entry of the dictionary and push everything else down one.

To sort the values I was using LINQ with the following code:

```
// Order by values.
var items = from pair in dictionary
            orderby pair.Value ascending
                select pair;

// Display results.
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, float> pair in items)
{
    Debug.Log(  "Key value: " + pair.Key + " Value: " + pair.Value + "\n"); 
}
```

By when I ran this on my iPad I was getting a JIT error in Xcode (the data is sent via a plugin from Xcode to Unity). I looked around and it turns out some LINQ functionality doesn't work well with Xcode.

Can someone please suggest another way in which I can sort my data in a similar way which doesn't rely on using LINQ?

*edit*
I need to clarify: with the values being streamed in from a third party device, I need a way to tie to the value to its key. I have a variety of devices sending in data but they all have unique constants which I'm using to tie the value to. That way I know which reading is coming from which device.

And as I didn't say, this is the xCode message I get when I run the above code:

> ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method
>   'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2>:GetEnumerator ()' while running with --aot-only.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an order.. their entries go into "buckets" If you need an ordered list.. a collection based on partitioning is not the answer for you.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I believed I found a way to have sorted my dictionary out using LINQ. The thing is, I need to be able to tie each value coming in to its constant, if I didn't I would just use an array or something. So I'm open to suggestions on alternatives.

Comment: "I was getting a JIT error in Xcode" - what error exactly?

Comment: Updated my answer to give more information

Comment: Have you seen this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/250803/executionengineexception-attempting-to-jit-compile.html and this: http://programmerinstincts.com/aot-jit-compile-solving-executionengineexception-attempting-jit-compile-method-problem-ios/ ? I believe, that your question, as it stands, has no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternate to Dictionaries, you can use list of classes.

i.e

```
class ClassName
{
    public float Field1 {get; set;}
    public string Field2 {get; set;}
}
```

Have a look at [List Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use a SortedList

or just use a normal List<> and call the sort.
you can provide your own sorting strategy by making the items implement IComparable

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of Tuple

```
 List<Tuple<string, float>> toPrint = new List<Tuple<string, float>>();
```

To read more on Tuples,

[Tuples in c#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple)

Comment: Will this only place my key in once? I don't want to fill out a list by having hundreds of the same keys in there. Ideally, all I want is one key with its value constantly updating